# Terraform: store the contents of a set of files into a single variable

Tags: terraform, hcl

This is in TF V0.12 if that helps
In a directory, I have a variable number of single-line files.
I need to somehow read the contents of them all concatenating them with a newline between and store the result into a single variable. (not an array of strings)
I know I can get the list of files to read using:

```
locals{
  my files=tolist(fileset("${var.file_path}", "**")) }
```

And if I only had a single file I know I can read in the contents by using

```
locals {
  file_value=file("${var.file_path}\\${local.my_files}") # if there was only a single file
}
```

But my brains just turned to cotton wool how I can do the read for multiple,  I feel like I should be using a count and a concatenate within a null resource but can't seem to work the logic out.
Is that the right path or how should I be doing it?

Comment: Why not use null resource local_exec and concatenate files locally first?

Answer (score 9):

We can break this problem down into three steps:

1. Enumerate the filenames matching your desired pattern.
2. Read the content of each file into memory.
3. Concatenate all of the file contents together.

We can reformulate the above into three local value expressions, with each one building on the previous one:

```
locals {
  filenames            = fileset(".", "${var.file_path}/**")
  file_contents        = { for fn in local.filenames : fn => file(fn) }
  file_contents_concat = join("\n", local.file_contents)
}
```

Alternatively, we can do all of those steps together in a single expression:

```
locals {
  file_contents_concat = join("\n", [
    for fn in fileset(".", "${var.file_path}/**") : file(fn)
  ])
}
```

Note that in the [`fileset`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/fileset.html) call I included `var.file_path` in the `pattern` argument rather than in the `path` argument because that way the resulting file paths will all be relative to the current working directory, and so we can just pass them directly to `file` without having to re-prepend `var.file_path` there.

(The separation between `path` and `pattern` for `fileset` is there to help with situations like mirroring a bunch of files into S3, where it's helpful to have the resulting paths be relative to the bucket root rather than the current working directory, but that sort of mapping isn't important here because the filenames don't appear in the result at all.)

Comment: trying a test this way I get 
    
    Error: Error in function call
      on main.tf line 7, in locals:
       7:   filenames            = fileset(".", "${var.file_path}/*")<br/>
        |----------------
        | var.file_path is "C:/path/test/"
     
     Call to function "fileset" failed: failed to trim path of match (): Rel: can't make 
     C:\path\test\test1.test.txt relative to ..

Comment: apologies for poor markup i can't seem to get it formatting for me today

Comment: Hmm... does your `var.file_path` include `..`? It looks like that's causing it to fail because the contract for `fileset` is to produce paths under the path given in the first argument, but `..` is not within `.`. If you do need to work in a parent dir then you will probably need to write it the way you originally had it, with `var.file_path` in the `path` argument and then re-prepend it in the `file` call. (Note that Terraform uses forward slashes for paths even on Windows, so that configurations can be portable between platforms.)

Comment: I get an error: file_contents_concat = join("\n", local.file_contents)
    |----------------
    | local.file_contents is object with 2 attributes

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate locally with null_resource.

```
resource "null_resource" "concatenate_my_files" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    working_dir = "${var.file_path}"
    command = <<EOF
      cat "${local.my_files}" > "${var.concatenated_file_name}"
EOF
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @mon that reminded me I should always KISS

Removing the complexity I ended up

```
resource "null_resource" "concatenate_my_files" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    working_dir = var.file_path
    command = <<EOF
cat * > my_temp_file
EOF
  }
}
```

I can then read this in as previous.